# Не работает простейшее веб приложение Spring

Tags: java, spring

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, в чем может проблема.
При первоначальном создании сервера TomCat 10.0.23 автоматически открывается в браузере Index.jsp , то есть сервер работает. Проблема с закрытым портом отпадает.
А при попытке попасть на http://localhost:8080/hello_world сервер выдает ошибку 404.

Контроллер

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello_world")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello_world";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

<display-name>MvcTest</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering/>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

ApplicationContextMVC.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="spring" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id = "templateResolver" class = "org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".html" />
    </bean>

    <bean id = "templateEngine" class = "org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine" >
        <property name="templateResolver" ref = "templateResolver" />
        <property name = "enableSpringELCompiler" value ="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

hello_world.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang = "en" >


<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title >My app</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно полный код ошибки?

Comment: добавил скрин ошибки

Comment: Код ошибки из консоли

Comment: добавил код ошибки с консоли

Comment: Я имел ввиду то, что на скрине красным текстом написано. Консоль среды разработки, а не браузера

Comment: добавил скрин с консоли, эти ошибки возникают при создании сервера

Comment: @Денис Покажи git с этим проектом. Проще так, чем просить тебя показать еще pom файл и показать ошибки нормально, а не скринами. :)

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh https://github.com/voiatile/MvcTest

Comment: @Денис У меня все работает. Проект запустил на Tomcat 9.0.62 Ничего не трогал в твоем коде. Попробуй удали томкат и снова поставь. Попробуй Томкат 9 версии. В Мавен сделай clean и затем package. Затем собранный варник задеплой в томкат.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Спасибо большое, помогла переустановка TomCat на версию 9.0.65. Теперь все работает!